# IIS7.5 GetHostNamesPerSite using C#

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5

```
List<string> GetHostNamesPerSite(string SiteName)
```

How can I use IIS in C# to GetHostNamesPerSite?

Comment: What do you mean? As in the site bindings?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get a list of all of the host header host names bound to a site:

```
public static List<string> GetHostNamesPerSite(string siteName)
{
  using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager())
  {
    Site site = sm.Sites.First(s => s.Name == siteName);
    return site.Bindings.Select(s => s.Host).ToList();
  }
}
```